# How to make a div 100% accross

Tags: css

So, I've been trying to make a div go straight across a webpage. Although, it still has space on the left side.

Here's my css:

```
div.transbox {
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
border: 1px solid black;
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
   width: 100%;
   width: 100vw;
}

div.transbox p {
margin: 5%;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
}
```

And here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/pen/

If you can, explain how to remove that space on the left, or if I'm using the wrong code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is because you've not cleared the body's default margin, like so:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

If you refer to the [w3c specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/body.html#body-display) for the body element you'll see it has a default value of 8 pixels.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. I'll mark your answer as the best answer in 7 minutes. Can't believe I forgot about that.

Comment: No problem. It's often the simple ones that catch you out! :)

Comment: 7 minutes has passed! Not that I'm counting ;)

Comment: I've given it, and sorry for the over time. :p